# Table rows / cells are the same height as the table

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I'm trying out the Quick Start example just to get familiar with Tabulator.
I copied the code verbatim from example.
When I load the table the rows are the same height as the table. i.e. only one row is visible at a time. 
I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to autofit the rows, or even make them a fixed height.

Local Server: EasyPHP Devserver 17.0
Browser: Chrome (latest)
Tabulator: 4.2

I've added layout:"fitData",  but that only effects the columns
I tried using max-height instead of height.

```js
//sample data
var tabledata = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Oli Bob",
    age: "12",
    col: "red",
    dob: "12/08/2017"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Mary May",
    age: "1",
    col: "blue",
    dob: "14/05/1982"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Christine Lobowski",
    age: "42",
    col: "green",
    dob: "22/05/1982"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Brendon Philips",
    age: "125",
    col: "orange",
    dob: "01/08/1980"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Margret Marmajuke",
    age: "16",
    col: "yellow",
    dob: "31/01/1999"
  },
];

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  height: 400, // set height of table to enable virtual DOM
  data: tabledata, //load initial data into table
  resizableRows: true,
  layout: "fitData",
  //layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
  columns: [ //Define Table Columns
    {
      title: "Name",
      field: "name",
      sorter: "string",
      width: 150
    },
    {
      title: "Age",
      field: "age",
      sorter: "number",
      align: "left",
      formatter: "progress"
    },
    {
      title: "Favourite Color",
      field: "col",
      sorter: "string",
      sortable: false
    },
    {
      title: "Date Of Birth",
      field: "dob",
      sorter: "date",
      align: "center"
    },
  ],
  rowClick: function(e, id, data, row) { //trigger an alert message when the row is clicked
    alert("Row " + id + " Clicked!!!!");
  },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="example-table"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please see the above example and check if you can recreate the error maybe you forgot to add the css file ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I don't understand the separation in your edit. Why is it now 2 code windows?
If I copy that to a file  (index.php or index.html)  with the var declarations at the top and the html below, I just get a blank white page.
If I copy your var declarations back into a script tag in the body of the html, and replace my local sourcing of the css and .js with the online version,  I still get the table with the rows at height 100%
It works here with "Run code snippet".

Answer (score 0):

Is this good ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="example-table"></div>
</body>

</html>


<script>
//sample data
var tabledata = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Oli Bob",
    age: "12",
    col: "red",
    dob: "12/08/2017"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Mary May",
    age: "1",
    col: "blue",
    dob: "14/05/1982"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Christine Lobowski",
    age: "42",
    col: "green",
    dob: "22/05/1982"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Brendon Philips",
    age: "125",
    col: "orange",
    dob: "01/08/1980"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Margret Marmajuke",
    age: "16",
    col: "yellow",
    dob: "31/01/1999"
  },
];

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  data: tabledata, //load initial data into table
  resizableRows: true,
  columns: [ //Define Table Columns
    {
      title: "Name",
      field: "name",
      sorter: "string",
      width: 150
    },
    {
      title: "Age",
      field: "age",
      sorter: "number",
      align: "left",
      formatter: "progress"
    },
    {
      title: "Favourite Color",
      field: "col",
      sorter: "string",
      sortable: false
    },
    {
      title: "Date Of Birth",
      field: "dob",
      sorter: "date",
      align: "center"
    },
  ]
});
</script>
```